# I'm getting NA errors when I switch around the order of format in the as.date function in R

Tags: r

I'm using the code below to try to change the date format of a file that I imported from a CSV file. It works fine and returns dates like "2013-09-21". However, I want it to return 9-21-2013. I tried changing the format to Y/d/m, but it returns all NAs. How can I fix this?

```
web <- read.csv("Web.csv", header = TRUE)
as.Date(web$CLAIM.DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Also, on a related note, how can I replace the column in the web data set with the values from as.date (when I get it correct)? Thanks!!

Comment: The `format` argument is telling `as.Date()` the current format so it knows how to correctly read the date in. It is not telling it the format you want displayed.

Comment: Since your data example seems to be the format Year-Month-Day, it's not wonder that you get `NA` with Y/d/m.

Answer (score 0):

```
> mydate <- "2013-09-21"
> as.Date(mydate)
[1] "2013-09-21"
> format(as.Date(mydate), '%m/%d/%Y')
[1] "09/21/2013"
```

And if you want to replace the column you can use:

```
web$CLAIM.DATE <- format(as.Date(web$CLAIM.DATE), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks bouncyball. That works in your example, but when I do it it converts the date variable into class of character. I checked the class before I ran the code, and it says 'Date, format': "2013-01-01" etc etc.  This is the code I used. 'code' format(as.Date(mydate), '%m/%d/%y') 'code' Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide some data or a reproducible example. I cannot recreate your error.